# Recursive function with condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

A sample data first

```
        set.seed(123) 
        dat <- tibble(x = sample(-10:10, size = 11,replace = T))

        # A tibble: 11 x 1
              x
            <int>
        1    -4
        2     6
        3    -2
        4     8
        5     9
        6   -10
        7     1
        8     8
        9     1
        10    -1
        11    10
```

I have a variable y with initial value of 2. I want to calculate the final value of y by adding `x` to y in a given time step using:

```
      y[i] = y[i-1] + x[i]    

     dat %>% mutate(y = accumulate(x, ~ .x + .y, .init = 2)[-1])

            # A tibble: 11 x 2
                  x     y
                <int> <dbl>
            1    -4    -2
            2     6     4
            3    -2     2
            4     8    10
            5     9    19
            6   -10     9
            7     1    10
            8     8    18
            9     1    19
            10    -1    18
            11    10    28
```

Howevr, the condition that I want to impose is that in a given time step, y cannot be > 10 or be negative. If y > 10, 10 and if y < 0, 0. Therefore, the actual
y (shown in y1 below) should be:

```
          # A tibble: 11 x 2
                  x     y    y1
                  <int> <dbl>
            1    -4    -2      0 (-2 converted to 0)
            2     6     4      6 
            3    -2     2      4
            4     8    10     10 (12 converted to 10)
            5     9    19     10 (19 converted to 10)
            6   -10     9      0  
            7     1    10      1
            8     8    18      9  
            9     1    19     10
            10    -1    18     9
            11    10    28    10  (19 converte to 10)
```

Comment: Dude. You've named the columns `x` and `y` when accumulate uses the nearly identical `.x` and .`y` as arguments. That makes for a very confusing example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to redefine the function that you use for `accumulate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123) 
dat <- tibble(x = sample(-10:10, size = 11,replace = T))
fn <- function(x, y) pmax(pmin(x + y, 10), 0)
dat %>% 
  mutate(y = accumulate(x, fn, .init = 2)[-1])
dat
# A tibble: 11 × 2
       x     y
   <int> <dbl>
1     -4     0
2      6     6
3     -2     4
4      8    10
5      9    10
6    -10     0
7      1     1
8      8     9
9      1    10
10    -1     9
11    10    10
```

How it works: `pmax` takes max of the two values, and `pmin` takes min, so you wrap the sum of `x+y` into upper and lower bounds to cap the result within the limits you need to.

Answer (score 3):

kgolyaev beat me by a few minutes with a very similar approach.

```
dat %>% mutate(y = accumulate(x, ~min(max(.x + .y, 0), 10), .init = 2)[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Nonetheless, it is clear and concise.